# C++, libsodium, secretbox

Tags: c++, encryption

in my project I use libsodium to encrypt a text.
I use this example, for a test, the example was taken from this [site](https://libsodium.gitbook.io/doc/secret-key_cryptography/secretbox):

```
#define MESSAGE ((const unsigned char *) "test")
#define MESSAGE_LEN 4
#define CIPHERTEXT_LEN (crypto_secretbox_MACBYTES + MESSAGE_LEN)

unsigned char key[crypto_secretbox_KEYBYTES];
unsigned char nonce[crypto_secretbox_NONCEBYTES];
unsigned char ciphertext[CIPHERTEXT_LEN];

crypto_secretbox_keygen(key);
randombytes_buf(nonce, sizeof nonce);
crypto_secretbox_easy(ciphertext, MESSAGE, MESSAGE_LEN, nonce, key);

unsigned char decrypted[MESSAGE_LEN];
if (crypto_secretbox_open_easy(decrypted, ciphertext, CIPHERTEXT_LEN, nonce, key) != 0) {
    /* message forged! */
}
```

It all works, but I have a few questions:

1. What is the encryption algorithm used in this example?
2. Is the algorithm safe from brute attacks?
3. If an attacker knew the length of the original text, the length of
   the encrypted text, and the nonce, would the text still be safe?

Comment: For question 1, see https://libsodium.gitbook.io/doc/secret-key_cryptography/secretbox#algorithm-details

Comment: I think all your questions are answered in the [documentation](https://libsodium.gitbook.io/doc/secret-key_cryptography/secretbox)

Comment: @AlanBirtles, so it takes a maximum of 32 characters, right?

Comment: I don't see any length limit in the documentation